# Testing data clear in power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am testing data save and clear the text input fields. When I click on submit button, I want to save all text input data to SharePoint list and navigate to the same original screen.

How can you clear text input fields after you submit the data?

After I press submit it reloads the same page with the old values in the text boxes.

Comment: Are you developing canvas app and using *form* control?

Comment: Yes, I am using canvas app and form control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave the controls empty after submitting, unlock the controls and then delete the values under **Default** properties, or it will return the default values even after being reset.

The form has a **Reset** function to reset itself in the *OnSuccess* property under *ACTION* by default. You can just add one more button and use **SubmitForm** function with it:

```
SubmitForm(SharePointForm1);
```

Please note that the **DefaultDate** values for **Date picker** controls will not be erased.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using below after you submit the SharePoint data:

```
ResetForm(<Form control name>)
```

Your complete formula on submit button will be something like:

```
SubmitForm(<Form control name>); ResetForm(<Form control name>)
```

Replace `<Form control name>` with the name of your actual form control.

If that doesn't work for you then try adding the same Reset function in `OnSuccess` property of your form control.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Reset function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-reset)